# Можно как-нибудь менять код html при помощи параметров

Tags: html, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

На сервере лежит файл index.html
Доступа к нему нет.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Та-дан<title>
</headl>
</html>
```

Существую ли способы поменять
title страницы, не меняя сам файл, чтобы название страницы для меня было другое?
Либо в адресную строку добавить какие-нибудь параметры?

Comment: Не существуют .

Comment: Если только для вас, то можно. Браузерным расширением.